# Email address validation on mail servers

Tags: web-services, email-validation

How to check if an email address exists at the time of signup, not in database but on the mail servers. for example when I enter an email-id in signup form, how to check if the id exists and is not a fake

Comment: Just mail a confirm link.

Comment: well if I do that then, the user will not be able to login until the id is confirmed, I want it in such a way that the user is able to login without confirming the email id, but the email id should be valid. like Facebook for example if we enter asdasd@asdasdasd.com in the email id field of Facebook signup form it gives the error "Please enter a valid email address."

Answer (score 0):

This service allows you to check up to 20 email addresses per day for free, or you can purchase their premium plan: https://tools.verifyemailaddress.io/

Their site also provides a link that explains the ["mailbox pinging"](https://tools.verifyemailaddress.io/Articles/Ping/How_To_Ping_Email_Address/) functionality which makes this possible, along with some limitations.

You can precede this with a simple check for a valid email address format. A quick online search will provide you with many code snippets that can do this.

Comment: well, I will have to copy each and every email from database, and do it manually, It should be like as soon as anyone enters an emailid in the signup form, it checks if its valid